# Get all the Controller & resources from the routes.php in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have just started using Laravel. I want to get the all possible routes using routes & with in those routes whom ever they are going to controller. I would like to know what methods are they are using.

I want to get all the routes automatically which ever controller i create in my `App/Http/Controllers`.

I would like to create a permission system for different users level (Dynamic) so it will be easy for admin to create different users with different permissions.

Is there any way i can do this?

I would like to display like this:

1) A page will be there in my `resources/views/users/premissions.blade.php`.

2) There will be all the controller mentioned with individual name and its methods like:

**PagesController**

- [checkbox] View
- [checkbox] Create
- [checkbox] Show
- [checkbox] Update
- [checkbox] Destroy

**PostsController**

- [checkbox] View
- [checkbox] Create
- [checkbox] Show
- [checkbox] Update
- [checkbox] Destroy

3) Then user will select the checkbox to provide the permission to the user. From the above controller.

Thank you! looking forward to get its solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, but you could get all routes with `Route::getRoutes()`.

Not tested in 5.2, but should do the work.

```
    foreach (Route::getRoutes() as $Route) {
        $Routes[] = [
            'methods' => $Route->getMethods(),
            'path' => $Route->getPath(),
            'action' => $Route->getActionName(),
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Yes i agree it should have been worked. But its showing this error `ReflectionException in Route.php line 264:
Class App\Http\Controllers\UsersController does not exist`

Comment: Yes your helped me. :)